# Why does the same signal need to be connected to the main circuit slot method to be triggerable?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread, qt-signals

I have two threads, a main thread and a sub-thread, and a signal in the main thread that's connected to the slot method in the main thread and the sub-thread respectively.

I emit this signal in the destructor of the main thread and want to trigger it when the main thread GUI window is closed.

I found that if I don't connect this signal with the main thread's slot method, the child thread's slot method can't trigger either.

**Notes:**

- Some details are omitted in the following code
- Signal: `testslot`
- Slot: `testsig`

Others are not important in this code, the important is:

```
connect(this,
            &Widget::testsig,
        m_check_serial_worker,
            &Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::testslot);
connect(this,
            &Widget::testsig,
        this,
            &Widget::testslot);
```

**Main thread:**

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("bootloader");

    Init_ComBoxs();
    Init_Card_Info_List();

    m_check_serial_worker = new Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker();
    m_check_serial_worker->moveToThread(&m_check_serial_thread);

    m_serial_comm_worker = new Serial_Comm_Worker();
    m_serial_comm_worker->moveToThread(&m_serial_comm_thread);

    connect(m_check_serial_worker,
            &Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Have_Change_Serial,
            this,&Widget::Update_Serial_List,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);

    connect(&m_check_serial_thread,&QThread::started,
            m_check_serial_worker,&Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Start_Check);


    connect(&m_serial_comm_thread, &QThread::finished,
            m_serial_comm_worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(&m_check_serial_thread,&QThread::finished,
            m_check_serial_worker,&QObject::deleteLater);

    connect(ui->operate_serial_switch_btn,&QPushButton::clicked,
                this,&Widget::On_Operate_Serial_Switch_Btn_Clicked);
    connect(ui->sel_dir_toolbtn,&QToolButton::clicked,
            this,&Widget::On_Sel_Dir_Toolbtn_Clicked);

    bool cnnret = connect(this,&Widget::Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread,
            m_check_serial_worker,&Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Stop_Cur_Thread,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);
    if(!cnnret){
        Custom_Tools::Print("connect failed");
    }
    m_serial_comm_thread.start();
    m_check_serial_thread.start();


    connect(this,&Widget::testsig,
            m_check_serial_worker,&Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::testslot);
    connect(this,&Widget::testsig,this,&Widget::testslot);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    emit testsig();
    emit Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread();
    if(ui->operate_serial_switch_btn->text() == QString("CLOSE")){
        Operator_Serial_Switch();
    }

    m_check_serial_thread.quit();
    m_check_serial_thread.wait();

    m_serial_comm_thread.quit();
    m_serial_comm_thread.wait();

    delete ui;

}

void Widget::testslot()
{
    Custom_Tools::Print("test slot frome main thread");
}
```

**Child thread:**

```cpp
void Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Stop_Cur_Thread()
{
    Custom_Tools::Print("Quit Slot");
    m_timer->stop();
}

void Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Start_Check()
{

    Do_Work();
    open_flag = true;
    m_timer = new QTimer;
    m_timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    connect(m_timer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Do_Work);
    m_timer->start(5000);

    m_odd_serial_list.clear();


}

void Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::Do_Work()
{
    QStringList tmp_str_list;

    tmp_str_list.clear();
    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        tmp_str_list += info.portName();
    }

    if(tmp_str_list != m_odd_serial_list){
        m_odd_serial_list = tmp_str_list;
        Custom_Tools::Print("Update available serial port!");
        emit Have_Change_Serial(tmp_str_list);
    }
    Custom_Tools::Print("Check Serials!");
}

void Check_Serial_Monitor_Worker::testslot()
{
    Custom_Tools::Print("test emit from child thread");
}
```

The same signal connects the sub-thread and the slot method in the main thread respectively. If the main thread is not connected, the sub-thread will not execute. Why is this ?

**Environment：**

- System: Windows 11
- Qt version: 5.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer, because in the destructor of the main thread, the program executes too fast, the signal is sent out, and the program is closed before it has time to execute.